# Updating columns based on a combine rows value on the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please assist if possible, I have used Stuff to combine rows into a single row based on other columns. However I want to turn each of the unique items into it's own column with a number showing if it exists, e.g. 1 or 0 and then doing the same for all subsequent rows?

I have been able to create the columns but I can't get them to update per whats in the one column.

[image]

But I want it to be dynamic so matter how many different names appear in categories it creates a new column and adds 1 or 0 if it appears or not

Comment: provide your sample data and expected output in table format

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some [sample data](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: The reference to "stuff" suggests that you are using SQL Server.  You can Google "SQL Server dynamic pivot" to find solutions to this problem.

Answer (score -1):

How about something like this for SQL Server?

strSQL = "SELECT Category, CASE WHEN Category IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsCategoryExist FROM MyTable"

Sample data (the 2nd column shows as 1 if the first column is non-blank):
    Cars, 1
    [Blank], 0
    Airplanes, 1
    Radios, 1